# How to find day difference between two dates?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

I was trying to make a simple program that finds the day difference between 2 dates that are inputted.

This is the code:

```
#program to find the day difference between one date and another
import calendar

date1Y = int(input("input year of date 1"))  #putting the input from user to an list in order
date1M = int(input("input month of date 1")) #I don't know how to do this efficiently
date1D = int(input("input day of date 1"))
date2Y = int(input("input year of date 2"))
date2M = int(input("input month of date 2"))
date2D = int(input("input day of date 2"))

list_date1 = [date1Y, date1M, date1D]  #lists of the first and second date in order Y/M/D
list_date2 = [date2Y, date2M, date2D]

days = 0

if list_date1(0) < list_date2(0) or (list_date1(0) == list_date2(0) and list_date1(1) < list_date2(1)):
    
    while (list_date1(0) != list_date2(0) and list_date1(1) != list_date2(1)):
         
        while (list_date1(1) <= 12): 
             a = calendar.monthrange(list_date1(0), list_date1(1))
             days_month = a[1]
             days += a[1]
             list_date1(1) += 1

        else : 
            list_date1(0) += 1
            list_date1(1) = 0
    

elif list_date2(0) < list_date1(0) or (list_date1(0) == list_date2(0) and list_date2(1) < list_date1(1)):

    while (list_date1(0) != list_date2(0) and list_date1(1) != list_date2(1)):

        while (list_date2(1) <= 12):
            a = calendar.monthrange(list_date2(0), list_date2(1))
            days_month = a[1]
            days += a[1]
            list_date2(1) += 1

        else :
            list_date2(0) += 1
            list_date2(1) = 0
    

if (date1D > date2D):  #adding the day differences of the 2 dates
    days = days + (date1D-date2D)

else :
    days = days + (date2D-date1D)

print("the number of days difference =", str(days))
```

Comment: `list_date1` and `list_date2` are lists, you need `list_date1[0]` to access them.

Comment: if you just need the difference, consider using `datetime.timedelta` (unless you want this as an exercise)

Comment: `from datetime import date` `days = (date(date2Y,date2M,date2D)-date(date1Y, date1M, date1D)).days`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both `list_date1` and `list_date2` are lists, accessing an element from it would use square brackets instead of regular ones. Try changing all of your `list_date#(#)` to `list_date#[#]`

For example, with a list `x = [1, 2, 3]`
printing `x[1]` would print `2`, because list indexes start at 0.